# function breaks ranged-based for

Tags: c++, for-loop, hashmap, iteration

Somehow, in the ranged-based `for` loop in `findLongestPath()`, the `dfs()` function makes it so the loop quits after the first iteration instead of going through every element to pass it to the function and find the max among the results. The structure is `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>`. The program is supposed to be solution of leetcode problem https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-string-chain/description/?envType=daily-question&envId=2023-09-23

Code provided to recreate the error(the answer is supposed to be 10):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <vector>

bool ifPred(std::string& first, std::string& second) {
    if (first.size() + 1 != second.size()) return false;
    int cnt = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
    while (i < first.size() && j < second.size()) {
        if (first[i] != second[j]) {
            cnt++;
            if (cnt > 1) return false;
        } else
            i++;
        j++;
    }
    return true;
}

static bool compareByLength(const std::string& a, const std::string& b) {
    return a.length() < b.length();
}

int binarySearchFirstNLengthString(const std::vector<std::string>& vec, int n) {
    int left = 0;
    int right = vec.size() - 1;
    int result = -1;
    while (left <= right) {
        int mid = left + (right - left) / 2;
        if (vec[mid].length() == n) {
            result = mid;
            right = mid - 1;
        } else if (vec[mid].length() < n) {
            left = mid + 1;
        } else {
            right = mid - 1;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

int dfs(std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& connected,
        std::unordered_map<int, int>& longestPath, int node) {
    if (longestPath.find(node) != longestPath.end()) {
        return longestPath[node];
    }
    int maxLength = 0;
    for (int neighbor : connected[node]) {
        maxLength =
            std::max(maxLength, 1 + dfs(connected, longestPath, neighbor));
    }
    longestPath[node] = maxLength;
    return maxLength;
}

int findLongestPath(std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>& connected) {
    std::unordered_map<int, int> longestPath;
    int maxPathLength = 0;

    for (auto pair : connected) {
        int node = pair.first;
        int dfss = dfs(connected, longestPath, node);
        if (dfss > maxPathLength) {
            maxPathLength = dfss;
        }
    }

    return maxPathLength + 1;
}

int longestStrChain(std::vector<std::string>& words) {
    std::sort(words.begin(), words.end(), compareByLength);
    int n = words.size(), max = 1, loc = 1;
    std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>> connected;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int p = binarySearchFirstNLengthString(words, words[i].size() + 1);
        if (p == -1) continue;
        for (int q = p;
             q < words.size() && words[q].size() == words[i].size() + 1; q++) {
            if (ifPred(words[i], words[q])) connected[i].push_back(q);
        }
    }
    return findLongestPath(connected);
}

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> A = {
        "cozddh",    "ferawpnpff", "ivftewfdn", "mq",        "zmq",
        "nwzmbq",    "rcozyddh",   "rcozyddhm", "czddh",     "hrcozyddhm",
        "vftewfdn",  "vtefdn",     "rpeyrgwm",  "wcjaki",    "jiddfyh",
        "nzmbq",     "xnvzrzc",    "zdh",       "utcc",      "peyrgwm",
        "pergwm",    "vftefdn",    "rcozddh",   "h",         "zddh",
        "tcc",       "nnwhszmbuq", "utgcc",     "nnwszmbq",  "jiddfh",
        "zmbq",      "ivtftewfdn", "vefdn",     "ferawpnff", "xnvzrc",
        "nnwhszmbq", "dh",         "nwszmbq"};
    std::cout << longestStrChain(A) << '\n';
}
```

The problem remains if we iterate through `unordered_map<int, vector<int>>` via a regular `for` loop. The bug was observed via VS Code debugger.

The iteration worked as expected when I replace

`int dfss = dfs(connected, longestPath, node);`

with

`dfss = 1;`

```
for (std::unordered_map<int, std::vector<int>>::iterator it = connected.begin();it!=connected.end();it++) {
    int node = (*it).first;
    int dfss = dfs(connected, longestPath, node);
    if (dfss > maxPathLength) {
        maxPathLength = dfss;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is this `longestStrChain` looking for? The program prints 3. What is the expected result?

Comment: Are you aware that `for (auto pair : connected)` makes `pair` a *copy* of the vector? Did you instead want `const auto& pair: connected`?

Comment: Are you aware that `compareByLength` is not a valid sort comparison? Sorting requires "strict weak ordering", which that function does not do.

Comment: I still don't understand what the program is supposed to do, but my _guess_ is that the correct answer is `4`.

Comment: You're modifying `connected` while iterating over, which is not allowed, it since `connected[node]` will implicitly insert `node` into `connected` if it doesn't exist.  Your program's behavior is therefore undefined.

Comment: @MilesBudnek Well spotted. I guess a `connected.reserve(words.size());` would solve that issue though.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Yes, that would work.   Better, IMO, would be to just check if `node` is in `connected` first and skip the loop if it's not (and pass a `const` reference so it can't be modified by accident).

Comment: @TedLyngmo indeed that solved the issue, I just don't get how. Also I can't see where connected is modified

Comment: @Olb Read about `operator[]`. It inserts a key/value pair if it's missing. If you have not reserved enough buckets already, this can cause rehashing, which in turn invalidates all iterators to the container.